# Servo selection Lightweight robot, 4 Legs, 3 joints per leg.

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, servo

I'm building a robot for my major work at school and need to select servo motors for the legs.
The robot will have 4 legs and each leg will have 3 joints so 12 servos are needed.
My robot will be similar to [this robot](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Based-Four-Legged-Robot/?ALLSTEPS) but mine will be slightly heavier and I want to have the most torque possible under $100 for all 12 so $8.33 per servo (a little over is ok).
I will also be using an arduino uno to control to robot and I want to have a servo shield if possible too.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following webpage has a list of servos, their torque specs, and their street prices (This list is for servos made by the same company as the servos in the Instructable you referenced):
http://www.servodatabase.com/servos/towerpro

For example, you can choose the SG-5010 with a stall torque of 8.0 kg*cm.

That website also lets you compare/tabulate specs of various other brands of servos, so you can make a decision that way.